# TypedValue Converting to String

Tags: android, android-resources

At random points while I'm using my Android application, LogCat is flooded with dozens of repetitions of the following 5 lines:

```
10-26 12:53:30.372  21270-21270 W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f0b00d8}
10-26 12:53:30.372  21270-21270 W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x1d/d=0xffe51c23 a=2 r=0x7f090047}
10-26 12:53:30.374  21270-21270 W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f0b008a}
10-26 12:53:30.375  21270-21270 W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f0b00d6}
10-26 12:53:30.375  21270-21270 W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f0b00d7}
```

Using the information from the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554876/how-to-identify-where-code-is-incorrect-if-i-get-warning-converting-to-string), I determined that it is trying to interpret nulls (0x0) as booleans (0x12), which makes no sense, as I'm never dealing with either nulls or booleans.

The resource IDs from the logs (r=0x?) point to views/view attributes within one of two layouts, which I'll include below.

The only places in my code where I reference those resource IDs are a) the CursorAdapter that uses the first layout, and b) a class that uses the second layout and I will include that code below as well.

I'm not sure if this is something to worry about. I know correlation does not imply causation, but when LogCat is flooded with those logs, scrolling through my app is noticeably janky.

Any help with figuring out what is going on would be appreciated.

Layout file #1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="72dp"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/event_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text_color"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/event_dates"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/event_name"
        android:text="Dates"
        android:textColor="@color/secondary_text_color"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/event_location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/event_name"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/event_dates"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Location"
        android:textColor="@color/secondary_text_color"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Layout file #2:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/event_type"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Header"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
</LinearLayout>
```

CursorAdapter:

```
public class EventCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    public String getKey(int position) {
        Cursor c = getCursor();
        c.moveToPosition(position);
        return c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Database.Events.KEY));
    }

    public EventCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
        super(context, c, flags);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_event, viewGroup, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView dates = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.event_dates);
        Date startDate = null, endDate = null;
        Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "Start: " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.Events.START)));
        try {
            startDate = new Date(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.Events.START)));
            endDate = new Date(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.Events.END)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Oops.
        }
        dates.setText(EventHelper.getDateString(startDate, endDate));

        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.event_name);
        name.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.Events.NAME)));

        TextView location = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.event_location);
        location.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.Events.LOCATION)));
    }
}
```

Other class:

```
public class EventTypeHeader extends ListHeader {

    public EventTypeHeader(String title) {
        super(title);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(Context c, LayoutInflater inflater, View convertView) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null || !(convertView.getTag() instanceof ViewHolder)) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_event_type_header, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.event_type);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.text.setText(getText());

        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I'll include what each resource ID references in my layout file

0x7f0b00d8: `event_type`

0xffe51c23: `primary` (my app's primary color)

0x7f0b008a: `event_name`

0x7f0b00d6: `event_dates`

0x7f0b00d7: `event_location`

Also, note that this is running on the 5.0 Preview. However, I still saw these logs back when I was on 4.4.4.

**EDIT #2**

After searching through the Android source code, I've discovered that the only place that "Converting to String" exists is in the class `android.content.res.TypedArray`.

However, I never even instantiate, import, or in any way use that class in my project! This just gets weirder and weirder.

**EDIT #3**

Per the request of a commenter, I have uploaded my `styles.xml` and `colors.xml` to a gist, which can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/nwalters512/23f265e94935ffba67f4).

Comment: +1 for teaching me janky. So the resource `r=0x7f0b00d8` for example refers to what? If you open your generated R.java file.

Comment: Definitely no other references. I'd do a string search for `primary_text_color` because this line: `Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x1d/d=0xffe51c23 a=2 r=0x7f090047}` suggests it is converting the colour (t=`0x1d`). Might be easier to track that one instance down.

Comment: Also have you done a clean?, sometimes generated resources get into a funny state.

Comment: Just cleaned to project; there was no change. I also searched the entire project for ```primary_text_color```, and there were only 4 references to it: its definition in ```colors.xml```, a line in ```R.java```, the above layout, and another unrelated layout.

Comment: on which device is this log from? does it happen even on emulator or nexus device?

Comment: I recently tested that; it occurs on my Nexus 5 running 5.0, but not my friend's identical phone. That's the really strange part.

Comment: If the same app running on phones with the same hardware and OS versions produces different outputs, one gets suspicious. My suspicion is that the print outs aren't from your app at all, but from some other app you have installed, that is not on your friends phone. Have you matched the printout PIDs with the PID of your app to ensure they really are from your app?

Comment: I removed the package name from the log for brevity, but all the logs contain the package name of my app.

Comment: Does it happen on the emumator ?

Comment: Can you post your `colors.xml` and `styles.xml`? Do you have any configuration-specific implementations of these files (i.e. `values-xx` folders?)

Comment: I will post those two files in a moment. I do not have any configuration-specific files that would be applicable here. EDIT I've posted the files in a gist; see the edit way at the bottom.

Comment: check this link may be it will helpful for you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903948/android-resources-converting-to-string

Comment: @Aditya believe me, I've already seen that question. It was of no help to me.

Comment: _Wild guessing now_: Does your device use `ART` instead of `Dalvik`?

Comment: It's running 5.0, so yes, it does. However, like I said, I didn't see this problem on a friend's identical device.

Comment: Android L is still a preview for Nexus 5. Maybe wait a bit for the release. Do not waste too much time on this one if your app does not crash.

Comment: The weird this is that my friend is running the same exact build, and he has no problems. And I could deal with a crash, but I can't deal with the massive lagging that this issue causes. If it can happen on my phone, it can happen on someone else's, no?

Comment: Maybe you can comment code little by little to see exactly the line of code that is causing those logs

Comment: I have no idea where I'd even start with that. My codebase is massive.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I filed a bug report with the Android team, as I still couldn't explain or fix this issue. The bug report is [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78322). A commenter suggested that I uncheck "Enable view attribute inspection" in the Developer Options. Lo and behold, this problem is now fixed! I don't remember ever checking that, which is weird, but at least I now know what causes this problem.

Comment: what does "Enable view attribute inspection" do?